# Build HashSet from a vector in Rust

Tags: vector, rust, hashset

I want to build a `HashSet<u8>` from a `Vec<u8>`. I'd like to do this

1. in one line of code,
2. copying the data only once,
3. using only `2n` memory,

but the only thing I can get to compile is this piece of .. junk, which I think copies the data twice and uses `3n` memory.

```
fn vec_to_set(vec: Vec<u8>) -> HashSet<u8> {
    let mut victim = vec.clone();
    let x: HashSet<u8> = victim.drain(..).collect();
    return x;
}
```

I was hoping to write something simple, like this:

```
fn vec_to_set(vec: Vec<u8>) -> HashSet<u8> {
    return HashSet::from_iter(vec.iter());
}
```

but that won't compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> <anon>:5:12
  |
5 |     return HashSet::from_iter(vec.iter());
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u8, found &u8
  |
  = note: expected type `std::collections::HashSet<u8>`
  = note:    found type `std::collections::HashSet<&u8, _>`
```

.. and I don't really understand the error message, probably because I need to RTFM.

Comment: FYI: in your first code, you don't need to clone the vector, you just need to declare it as mutable. Either by `let mut victim = vec;` or in the argument list by: `fn vec_to_set(mut vec: Vec<u8>)`.

Comment: You're not using the *O* notation correctly. _O(n) = O(2n) = O(3n) = O(c*n)_. The point is that constants don't matter. I think that it is clear what you mean but you should probably say just "_2n_ memory" or something instead.

Comment: Thanks Lii, if `O(n) == O(2n)` then what is the right way to express that something takes twice as long? It seems useful to be able to compare `n` and `2n`. Thanks.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Because the operation does not need to consume the vector¹, I think it *should not* consume it. That only leads to extra copying somewhere else in the program:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn hashset(data: &[u8]) -> HashSet<u8> {
    HashSet::from_iter(data.iter().cloned())
}
```

Call it like `hashset(&v)` where `v` is a `Vec<u8>` or other thing that coerces to a slice.

There are of course more ways to write this, to be generic and all that, but this answer sticks to just introducing the thing I wanted to focus on.

¹This is based on that the element type `u8` is `Copy`, i.e. it does not have ownership semantics.

Comment: This doesn't compile anymore.

Comment: Why do we need to use `from_iter` instead of `iter`? Could you explain the difference between them?

Answer (score 56):

The following should work nicely; it fulfills your requirements:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn vec_to_set(vec: Vec<u8>) -> HashSet<u8> {
    HashSet::from_iter(vec)
}
```

`from_iter()` works on types implementing [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), so a `Vec` argument is sufficient.

Additional remarks:

- you don't need to explicitly `return` function results; you only need to omit the semi-colon in the last expression in its body
- I'm not sure which version of Rust you are using, but on current stable (1.12) `to_iter()` doesn't exist

Answer (score 32):

#### Converting  Vec to HashSet

Moving data ownership

```
let vec: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let hash_set: HashSet<u8> = vec.into_iter().collect();
```

Cloning data

```
let vec: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let hash_set: HashSet<u8> = vec.iter().cloned().collect();
```

Comment: `collect` uses `FromIterator` — this is the same as the above two answers except more verbose.

Comment: fixed type error. This code does not require repeating HashSet in the conversion code

Comment: There's no repeating of `HashSet` in the original answers either. Their code: `let hash_set = HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec);` vs yours: `let hash_set: HashSet<usize> = vec.into_iter().collect()`

Comment: You removed the type in your first example to hide the repeat of HashSet code 1: ```let hash_set: HashSet<usize> = HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec);``` code 2: ```let hash_set: HashSet<usize> = vec.into_iter().collect()```   Example restored