# Cannot infer type for type parameter `S` when using HashSet::from_iter

Tags: rust

I am trying to solve an online challenge that involves comparing two sets. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39803426/3697191) answer to convert my `Vec<i32>` output to `HashSet`

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

struct Solution {}

impl Solution {
    pub fn solve(nums: Vec<i32>, k: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
        // todo, return dummy for now
        return vec![1, 2];
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        HashSet::from_iter(Solution::solve(vec![1, 2, 3], 2)),
        HashSet::from_iter(vec![1i32, 2i32])
    )
}
```

For reasons I don't understand yet, the compilation fails:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         HashSet::from_iter(Solution::solve(vec![1, 2, 3], 2)),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `S` declared on the struct `HashSet`
```

It works fine for `HashSet::from_iter(vec![1i32, 2i32])`

I tried adding a type annotation like `HashSet::from_iter::<Vec<i32>>` with no avail. I also read the [source implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.43.1/src/std/collections/hash/set.rs.html#950-961) but still can't figure out what makes the compiler complain.

I can work around it by declaring it explicitly or construct the `HashSet` with a for loop and `insert`s, but I would like to understand what is going on here.

I'm using Rust 1.43.1.

Comment: FYI, there's an issue raised on the Rust Github repo for this behavior: [HashMap::from_iter doesn't compile without explicitly supplying the hasher](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90879)

Comment: Some interesting further reading on this topic: https://faultlore.com/blah/defaults-affect-inference/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the [answer from Kitsu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950005/155423) is subtly incorrect since it suggests that Rust cannot infer the type of `T` because here may be an iterator implemented for a type `P` that collects a different type `T` (more on this at the end).

#### What's really happening

In fact, type inference for type `S` in `HashSet<T, S>` has nothing to do with the type of `T`. The issue is that there is no information in your program that allows the compiler to infer the type of `S`.

It is correct that adding a type parameter is sufficient to resolve the ambiguity:

```
HashSet::<i32>::from_iter(vec![1, 2, 3]);
```

This has *nothing* to do with the actual type you specify. Indeed, this works as well:

```
HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec![1, 2, 3]);
```

The reason is that the definition of `HashSet` in the standard library includes a default type for `S`:

```
pub struct HashSet<T, S = RandomState> {
    base: base::HashSet<T, S>,
}
```

By writing `HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec![1, 2, 3]);` you're telling the compiler that it should use the default type for `S`, which is `RandomState`.

#### What about multiple implementations?

[Kitsu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950005/155423) states that type inference fails for `S` because there might be multiple implementations of `FromIterator`. This is incorrect, but having multiple implementations can cause type inference to fail for `T`.

Consider this example:

```rust
fn iterator_demo() {
    use std::collections::HashSet;
    use std::hash::{BuildHasher, Hash};
    use std::iter::FromIterator;

    struct Empty;

    impl<T, S> FromIterator<Empty> for HashSet<T, S>
    where
        T: Eq + Hash,
        S: BuildHasher + Default,
    {
        fn from_iter<I>(iter: I) -> HashSet<T, S>
        where
            I: IntoIterator<Item = Empty>,
        {
            iter.into_iter().for_each(drop);
            HashSet::default()
        }
    }

    let x = HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec![Empty, Empty]);
}
```

This causes type inference to fail; note that this is a failure to infer `T`, not `S`:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `HashSet<T>`
  --> src/lib.rs:22:13
   |
22 |     let x = HashSet::<_>::from_iter(vec![Empty, Empty]);
   |         -   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |         |
   |         consider giving `x` the explicit type `HashSet<T>`, with the type parameters specified
```

Specifying the type resolves this ambiguity:

```
let x = HashSet::<String>::from_iter(vec![Empty, Empty]);
```

Credit to matt1992 on the Rust Discord for helping me to understand what's really happening here.

Comment: Having written more Rust since I asked this, this answer indeed seems accurate when it comes down to the reason. Indeed in the absence of more than one impl of from_iter, rust resolves T automatically. @Evan is there a reason why Rust cannot infer to use default S = RandomState ?

Comment: I think for type inference to succeed it must be unambiguous. If you specify `HashMap::<_>::from_iter` then `S` can only be `RandomState`. If you don't, then HashMap could have any `<T,S>` type params. The compiler could guess you mean `<i32, RandomState>` but that would just be a guess, and the compiler doesn't make guesses.

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler cannot use the default S.  If I want a non-default S, I need to specify it explicitly.  The compiler does not have to "guess" anything.  That it works with `::<_>` but not without is perplexing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the [`FromIterator::from_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#tymethod.from_iter) declaration, you've been using:

```rust
fn from_iter<T>(iter: T) -> Self
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = A>,
```

After specifying `HashSet` compiler can deduce that `Self` is `HashSet<S>` for some `S`. `T` for your particular case can be deduced as a `Vec<i32>: IntoIterator<Item = i32>` (for the second line that is resolved after you explicitly specified an integer type).

But still, `S` is not deduced because, in general, you may have an implementation that collects `HashSet<u64>` from `IntoIterator<Item = u8>`. So compiler cannot understand what are items of the collected type. Then if you swap the expressions of the `assert_eq` error source changes:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    HashSet::from_iter(vec![1i32, 2i32]),
/*
   |
15 |     HashSet::from_iter(vec![1i32, 2i32]),
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `S` declared on the struct `HashSet`
*/
    HashSet::from_iter(Solution::solve(vec![1, 2, 3], 2)),
)
```

The solution is fairly straightforward: you need to specify the item type of your `HashSet`:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    HashSet::<i32>::from_iter(Solution::solve(vec![1, 2, 3], 2)),
    HashSet::from_iter(vec![1i32, 2])
)
```

Comment: the answer makes sense, Is the compiler automatically able to infer S for the second one from vec macro once the first one is explicitly type annotated? or is there some special behaviour there?

Comment: Yes, similar to `if Vec::<usize>::new() == vec![] {}` statement. The second `Vec`'s type don't need to be specified since it deduced from the first.

Comment: >But still, `S` is not deduced because, in general, you may have an implementation that collects `HashSet<u64>` from `IntoIterator<Item = u8>`.

Interesting. Do you have any examples for types where this is implemented?