# Compound `HashSet` operations in Rust OR How to get an explicit difference/union of `HashSet`s in Rust

Tags: rust, hashset

I want perform the following, in pseudocode:

```
(a, b, c) = (HashSet(...), HashSet(...), HashSet(...))

(a, b, c) = (a - b - c, b - a - c, c - a - b)
```

In Rust I tried something like this:

```rust
fn get_random_set(...) -> HashSet<String> {
    ...
}

// Sets of randomly generated "words" that define behavior of the whole program.
let action_plus: HashSet<String> = get_random_set();
let action_minus: HashSet<String> = get_random_set();
let action_new_line: HashSet<String> = get_random_set();
```

Now we are to exclude all the common "words" from these `HashSet`s.
I learned that `difference` and `union` methods return `Difference` and `Union` iterators. And if I do this:

```rust
let action_plus = HashSet::from(action_minus.union(&action_new_line).collect::<Vec<String>>());
```

I receive this:

```
the trait `From<Vec<String>>` is not implemented for `HashSet<_, _>`
```

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: I think this answer has a code snippet that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803237/build-hashset-from-a-vector-in-rust

Comment: Sometimes`from` isn't the answer, it's `collect()` on an `into_iter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to remove any element that's in more than one set from all the sets. Since you are only removing elements, you don't need to clone any strings, and you can perform all operations in place. If your sets are called `a`, `b` and `c`, you can use this code:

```
a.retain(|x| b.remove(x) | c.remove(x));
b.retain(|x| c.remove(x));
```

This will first remove any element in the intersections between `a` and `b` as well as `a` and `c`, respectively, from both sets, and then all elements in the intersection between `b` and `c`. Overall, this should be much faster than the approaches discussed in the other answers (though I didn't do any benchmarks).

Note that it's important that the first line uses the non-shortcircuiting `|` operator rather than `||`. The last operand, `c.remove(x)`, obviously has a side effect, so we can't skip it. Otherwise, elements that are in all three sets would not be removed from `c`.

Answer (score 5):

Collect directly into `HashSet` instead of `Vec` using [impl FromIterator for HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E-for-HashSet%3CT,+S%3E).

That is:

```rust
let action_plus: HashSet<_> = action_minus.union(&action_new_line).collect();
```

As Chayim said in the comments you could also use `|` (`BitOr`) operator, since `HashSet` [implements it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitOr%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) and as the docs say it:

> Returns the union of self and rhs as a new HashSet<T, S>

If you look at it's implementation you can see, that it does basically the same as the code above (although it clones items from those sets):

```rust
impl<T, S> BitOr<&HashSet<T, S>> for &HashSet<T, S>
where
    T: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    S: BuildHasher + Default,
{
    type Output = HashSet<T, S>;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: &HashSet<T, S>) -> HashSet<T, S> {
        self.union(rhs).cloned().collect()
    }
}
```

`HasSet` also implements [BitAnd](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitAnd%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) (`&`) operator for creating an intersection, [Sub](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-Sub%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) (`-`) for creating a set difference and [BitXor](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitXor%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) (`^`) for creating a symmetric difference.

You can use those convenience operators, however they can be off-putting when one does not expect them, so use them carefully.

Comment: Or, shorter, `&action_minus | &action_new_line`.

Comment: Thank you all guys, it's definitely what I wanted to implement! I'll read documentation more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect directly into a `HashSet`.

```rs
let a = get_random_set();
let b = get_random_set();
let c = get_random_set();
let a_minus_b_minus_c = a
    .difference(&b)
    .cloned()
    .collect::<HashSet<_>>()
    .difference(&c)
    .cloned()
    .collect::<HashSet<_>>();
```

`cloned` is necessary to convert the output from `HashSet<&String>` to `HashSet<String>`, since `difference` requires sets of the same type. You don't need the last `cloned` if you're okay with `a_minus_b_minus_c` being `HashSet<&String>`.

However, it's easier to just use the subtraction operator. `HashSet` has [an implementation of `Sub`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-Sub%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) that takes both operands by reference, so you need to add a reference each time.

```rs
let a_minus_b_minus_c = &(&a - &b) - &c;
```

There's also:

- [`BitAnd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitAnd%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) for intersection `&a & &b`
- [`BitOr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitOr%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) for union `&a | &b`
- [`BitXor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#impl-BitXor%3C%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E%3E-for-%26HashSet%3CT,+S%3E) for symmetric difference `&a ^ &b`

Note that all these clone the values in the set and return a new set, so they're not optimally efficient. If you need more performance, you could do the operation manually by modifying the first set with [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.retain) (difference, intersection) or [`extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend) (union), or by manually making a new set that holds references.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helped me to understand it more deeply and to resolve the problem I encountered.